# OneDrive Rest API too many requests error when try to download file

Tags: c#, onedrive

I use rest api

> https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/{fileID}/content

to download OneDrive file

When i tried to download multiple files from OneDrive response return error:

`The remote server returned an error: (429) Too Many Requests.`

I tried to use Retry-After response header to wait before send another request but didn't work.

Is there any solution or work around for this issue?

My sample code in c#:

```
try
{
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/{fileID}/content");
  request.Method = "GET";
  request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer {accessToken}");
  WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
  Stream fileStream = response.GetResponseStream();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
  HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
  int retryAfter = 0;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(res.Headers["Retry-After"]))
   {
     retryAfter = int.Parse(res.Headers["Retry-After"]);
   }
  Thread.Sleep(retryAfter);
  //re-call same request function
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see how you're handling the response header. Please share the entire code.

Comment: The problem handling before i read the stream, throwing web exception when i tried to get response

Comment: I edited the question for it